# Deleting dataGridView1_CellContentClick() from C# code results in build failure - Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

If I never double-click on a freshly created DataGridView control, the `dataGridView1_CellContentClick()` handler is not created, yet the application builds and runs without any problem.

But once I create this `dataGridView1_CellContentClick()` handler by double-clicking the DataGridView control, **then delete it**, I receiving this **build** failure:

> error CS1061: 'App1.Form1' does not contain a definition for
>   'dataGridView1_CellContentClick' and no extension method
>   'dataGridView1_CellContentClick' accepting a first argument of type
>   'App1.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Why?

How does the framework know that I created it?

Is there a correct way of removing this handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to delete it from the designer.cs file as well as from your code behind code.

In the error list, just dbl click the error. It will take you there.

Cheers

Comment: +1 for the tip of double-clicking the error. Done. Works. Accepting (in 10 minutes).

Answer (score 4):

When you create that event handler, Visual Studio will also assign the event in the `.designer.cs` file, so that the form knows what method to call when the event is raised.

You are basically deleting the method, and not what calls the method.

Another way of deleting the event is to get the control and look at it in the Properties window. Blank out the event in the Events listing, and then remove the method itself.

Comment: Excellent. That's what I was suspecting. What is the proper way of removing that event handler? +1

Comment: Just edited to show another way. However it is generally easiest to just remove the event handler and then let the error output show you where it's used and remove it manually.